# Remove parent node and keep its children

Tags: java, xml, dom

### i have this XML in want to remove link tag and keep all its children

input xml :

```
  <P>
  <LINK TYPE="ERRATUM" DOI="">
    Der Kommentar zum Artikel Schaefer et al. in Heft 4/91 (S. 238) wurde
    nicht von PD Dr.
    <EM EMTYPE="ITALIC">M. Stöckle</EM>
    (Urologische Klinik, Mainz), sondern von PD Dr.
    <EM EMTYPE="ITALIC">O. Schofer</EM>
    (Kinderklinik der Universität, Mainz) verfasst.
  </LINK>
  </P>
```

output xml :

```
  <P>

    Der Kommentar zum Artikel Schaefer et al. in Heft 4/91 (S. 238) wurde
    nicht von PD Dr.
    <EM EMTYPE="ITALIC">M. Stöckle</EM>
    (Urologische Klinik, Mainz), sondern von PD Dr.
    <EM EMTYPE="ITALIC">O. Schofer</EM>
    (Kinderklinik der Universität, Mainz) verfasst.

  </P>
```

i tried this code but no success!

```
private void visitRecursively(Node node, Document document, String tagToRemove) {

    // get all child nodes
    NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {

        // get child node

        Node childNode = list.item(i);

        if(childNode != null){
            if(childNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                if(childNode.getNodeName().equals(tagToRemove)){

                    NodeList nodeList = childNode.getChildNodes();
                    Node parentNode = childNode.getParentNode();
                    System.out.println("parent= "+parentNode.getNodeName());
                    for(int j = 0 ; j < nodeList.getLength() ;  ++j ){
                            parentNode.appendChild(nodeList.item(j));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        visitRecursively(childNode, document, tagToRemove);
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Show us some code.  what have you tried?

Comment: currently for the sake of doing it i renamed the node to `tagtoremove` and then did a string replacement `""`. but i need a better method using DOM.

Comment: Someone else asked almost this exact question today.  I'll try and find it.

Comment: Here's how to do it with JaxB http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727131/how-to-ignore-some-tags-in-xml-in-jaxb

Answer (score 0):

For line-based formatting I'd just parse the text as a List and remove the line(s) including "`<LINK`" or "`</LINK`". Then trim the List to size, removing any blank rows.

Probably quicker than messing around with recursive manipulation of the NodeList.