# How to ignore some tags in XML in Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

my xml file is below:

```
<ExternalCases>
    <ignoreTag>
        <CashLess>
            <caseType>CashLess</caseType>
            <claimNo>9</claimNo>
            <status>Open</status>
        </CashLess>
    </ignoreTag>
</ExternalCases>
```

i want to ignore `<ignoreTag>` and i want `<CashLess>` tag in my Unmarshaller process.

my class like below:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ExternalCases")
public class ExternalCases {

    List<CashLess> cashLess;

    @XmlElement(name="CashLess", required=false)
    public List<CashLess> getCashLess() {
        return cashLess;
    }
    public void setCashLess(List<CashLess> cashLess) {
        this.cashLess = cashLess;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Cool question, is about my issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ignoring `ignoreTag`

You could create a StAX filtered `XMLStreamReader` and have JAXB unmarshal that to ignore one or more XML elements.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html#createFilteredReader%28javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader,%20javax.xml.stream.StreamFilter%29

Below is a link to a full example I gave in an answer to a similar question:

- [JAXB filtered parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949265/jaxb-filtered-parsing/5950542#5950542)

### If `ignoreTag` is a Grouping Element

If instead `ignoreTag` is a grouping element for the collection then you could map it as:

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name="ignoreTag")
@XmlElement(name="CashLess", required=false)
public List<CashLess> getCashLess() {
    return cashLess;
```

Comment: it is working but instead of particular tag i want general solution.
in place of <ignoreTag> any tag will come.

Comment: @Rajesh - General solution then would be to use the `StreamFilter`.

Answer (score 0):

Use answers of these questions::

[JAXB ignoring xml tag attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188599/jaxb-ignoring-xml-tag-attribute)

[JAXB - Ignore element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044042/jaxb-ignore-element)

might be helpful!!!

Comment: my thing is, i don't want to delete entire <ignoreTag> tag, just ignore <ignoreTag> tag and need to populate <CashLess> content.